# How to show a Telegram video preview in a message by using the link of the video file

Tags: telegram

I know there is some special websites like *Youtube, Vimeo and...* that I can upload my video on one of them and put its link in the message to Telegram show its large video preview under the message and play it by its *InApp-Player*.
[image]

But I want know is it possible to show the **large video preview** (like *Youtube* video previews under a Telegram message) by the link of the `MP4` file or a *page* on a *personal* host? Is it possible with open-graph?

Comment: 2k views and no answer :(. Did you figure this out on your own?

Comment: @Livo, Short answer is no, unless Telegram change their codes in its application. As you mentioned no one had given an answer, I decided to write my conclusion about this issue in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68173114/1474613).

Answer (score 0):

During my researches (at 2018) I came to the conclusion that there is no way yet. Actually it is related to the some static codes in the Telegram App.

I means they used something like a `switch case` in their codes about *YouTube* and *some other websites* and **unfortunately they do not write their code dynamically (for example based on checking a special meta tag,** such as og-tags).

**Then only ways that I found:**

- Using the video on YouTube and several websites that Telegram support them to show large preview
- Uploading the video on a Telegram channel and use its link
- Request Telegram about this issue and wait for next updated